# What are some good resources to learn about geophysics?

Tags: geophysics, resources

What are some good textbooks and online resources for learning about geophysics? That is, physics, as it relates to the earth's geology, shape, and internal structure.

Comment: This strikes me as a "shopping list question" - perhaps not a good precedent to set on a new site. (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)

Comment: I disagree I think this question is good for a new site on the topic, and here is a precedent from another stackexchange site:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275/best-maths-books-for-non-mathematicians

Comment: That question is much more specific (for non-mathematicians). I like these kind of questions (Stats.SE has a few good ones), but I think you need to narrow it down to a more specific field (e.g. physical oceanography), or a specific type of resource (e.g. pop-science walk-through books).

Comment: Or maybe the term geophysics is more specific than I thought...

Comment: We talked about these types of questions (questions asking for a list of literary works) [here on meta](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/11/are-list-questions-welcome).

Comment: @naught101: I appended a "definition" to geophysics in order to make the term as specific as possible, and voted to open the question in its current form.

Comment: This website hosts applied geophysics courses http://geosci.xyz/. It was put together by University of British Columbia and several other entities. They go over the basics and delve into every traditional method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also strongly suggest the courses available on the coursera platform under the category "Energy & Earth Sciences" [here](https://www.coursera.org/courses?orderby=upcoming&cats=energy).

Answer (score 7):

There are two universally loved geophysics texts : [Turcotte and Shubert](http://books.google.com/books/about/Geodynamics.html?id=-nCHlVuJ4FoC)  and [Stein and Wyessesion](http://epsc.wustl.edu/seismology/book/). Both are upper division/lower graduate level texts. [Fowler](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Solid_Earth.html?id=PifkAotvTroC) is great if you do not have a strong mathematical background (multivariate calculus). Beyond that, it might be difficult to get a a good understanding without an Introductory physics course, and a few semesters of calculus. A good way to learn about geophysics, is in fact, just learning about physics and mathematics in general. Hopefully this stack exchange will also become a good resource.

Comment: +1 for Fowler. As well as geodynamics, geophysics can also include exploration geophysics, where it seemed each sub-discipline had its own book.

Answer (score 4):

Geophysics has many flavors to it. Prof Claerbout's site has a lot of free stuff which are a good introduction to one part of it.

http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/prof/